# Was the Prophet (ﷺ) given a choice about being the apostle, or simply commanded to to?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, free-will

Did Allah *ask* the Prophet (ﷺ) if he would be His Messenger, or command him to?  Essentially, was there a point where *purely theoretically* the Prophet (ﷺ) could have said no (though obviously that would never have happened)?

Comment: According to my knowledge, the answer is no. All prophets and messengers were selected without someone’s request, and they can’t be replaced. Because, God wished so. And if God wishes to select Muhammad as His messenger, then he can’t tell God that He doesn’t want to be a prophet. That would go against Him. And God chided him without to ask his permission. He does not require anyone’s permission, but we do require His permission.